How to overload an object attribute type for mypy?
How to fix the [assignment] error raised by mypy when an object attribute type is different from its parent?
For instance, consider this Operation class. mypy complains about replace being a str and overloading the type from str.replace.
from enum import StrEnum


class Operation(StrEnum):
    add = "add"
    replace = "replace"
    remove = "remove"

The mypy output:
 error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", base class "str" defined the type as "Callable[[str, str, str, SupportsIndex], str]")  [assignment]

How can I solve this, possibly without renaming the attribute?

I dont't think this is possible. str wants Operation.add.replace to be a function and Enum wants Operation.add.replace to be an Enum. This is a conflict. Either rename the enum members or don't use a StrEnum
